# Pulse Audio settings in XFCE

Tags: audio, debian, microphone, xfce, pulse-audio

Almost every common graphical environment, I know, has a program/dialog where you can change the volume of your devices AND of every stream which is playing sound. But I'm not able to find such a dialog on Debian (jessie) XFCE. The only thing I find is a dialog where I can change the volume of the devices.

I need to change these settings to configure which microphone Pulse Audio should use by default. I need to change that because the microphone isn't working and I think this is because Pulse Audio tries to get sound input from the wrong sound card.

I already googled a lot about this problem but only found people which had other problems. But nothing i found did help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may have to install `pavucontrol`. XFCE is minimalist, so is expected that some settings are not found. To install it just type:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Comment: For more audio options in Xfce panel: https://askubuntu.com/q/107277/925128